# MySql: stop script if SELECT != (certain result)

Tags: mysql

I have a data cleanup script that I execute in Mysql Workbench in Windows. At the beginning of the script I have:

```
select @@hostname;
-- WARNING: it HAS to be `srv-datatest`

(+ the rest of the script)
```

I want the script to stop at that line if the condition (@@hostname = 'srv-datatest') is not met.

---

Things that I've tried:

How to throw an exception:

```
DECLARE invalid_database CONDITION FOR 1051;
SIGNAL invalid_database;
-- DECLARE is not accepted by my workbench, and it lacks the "if" part anyway
```

How to do an IF on a select:

```
SELECT IF(@@hostname='srv-datatest','yes','no');   
-- It lacks the "stop here" part
```

Comment: See answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3560149/1503018

Comment: @sectus Thanks for the suggestion. I've managed to take one of those solutions and modify it to my needs (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44697123/831138)).

Answer (score 0):

create a stored procedure that will perform your process and test.

your script in mysql workbench should only call your stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run it without stored procedures, using [this ingenious solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23750330/831138):

```
SET @hostname :=  (SELECT @@hostname);
SET @condition = (@hostname='srv-datatest');
SET SESSION sql_mode = if(@condition, @@SESSION.sql_mode, 'Script stopped. Check condition.');
```

In this code:

- If `@condition=1`, the script will run smoothly.
- If `@condition=0` it will throw an exception, showing the message error.